# Capturing commented text in an XML

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, xml-comments

I am trying to collect information from the World Bank. In particular, data from this website.

https://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/3761/get-microdata

The "DDI/XML" link  contains the metadata behind this dataset.  If you download the DDI/XML file, and search for "a3_1", you will notice that the data under the tag "qstnLit" has important information commented out, for example:

"[CDATA[ Please identify which of the following you consider the most important development priorities in Vietnam. (Choose no more than THREE) - Food safety ]]"

I can't seem to collect this information:  My code is the following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = "VNM_2020_WBCS_v01_M.xml"
import pandas as pd

with open(file, "r", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
                    sauce = f.read()
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, features = "lxml")

ref = pd.DataFrame()
soup = soup.select("codeBook")[0].select("dataDscr")[0].select("var")

for txt in soup:
                    try:
                        part = pd.DataFrame(data = {"ID"    : [txt.attrs["name"]],
                                                    "Qn"    : [txt.find("qstn").find("qstnlit").text],
                                                    "Lbl"   : [txt.find("labl").text],
                                                    "Max"   : [txt.find(attrs = {"type":"max"}).text],
                                                    "Min"   : [txt.find(attrs = {"type":"min"}).text]
                                                        })
                        ref = ref.append(part)
                    except:
                        pass
```

I can pick up non-commented out text, but no tex that has been commented

Is there a way to recognise comments?

Comment: A `CDATA` block isn't a comment; it's just text that's protected from accidentally being parsed as XML. CDATA means "Character Data", so essentially it's just a long string value. You should be able to read it like any other text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a different problem than you've described in your question. If I run your code as written, it prints this warning:

> /usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bs4/builder/**init**.py:545:
> XMLParsedAsHTMLWarning: It looks like you're parsing an XML document
> using an HTML parser. If this really is an HTML document (maybe it's
> XHTML?), you can ignore or filter this warning. If it's XML, you
> should know that using an XML parser will be more reliable. To parse
> this document as XML, make sure you have the lxml package installed,
> and pass the keyword argument `features="xml"` into the
> BeautifulSoup constructor.

And produces no output (so how can we tell if it's working or not?).

If we modify the code to address that warning:

```
with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    sauce = f.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce, features="xml")
```

And to get rid of that blank `except`, which you should never use, so
that the for loop looks like this:

```
for txt in soup:
    part = pd.DataFrame(
        data={
            "ID": [txt.attrs["name"]],
            "Qn": [txt.find("qstn").find("qstnlit").text],
            "Lbl": [txt.find("labl").text],
            "Max": [txt.find(attrs={"type": "max"}).text],
            "Min": [txt.find(attrs={"type": "min"}).text],
        }
    )
    ref = ref.append(part)
```

We see it fail like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/souptest.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Qn": [txt.find("qstn").find("qstnlit").text],
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Now we're seeing useful information! That tells us that
`txt.find('qstn')` has returned no results, so maybe we should check
for that.

A second problem we see here is that you have mis-spelled `qstnLit` as
`qstnlit`, so we need to fix that, too.

That gets us:

```
for txt in soup:
    qn = txt.find('qstn')
    if not qn:
      continue

    part = pd.DataFrame(
        data={
            "ID": [txt.attrs["name"]],
            "Qn": [qn.find("qstnLit").text],
            "Lbl": [txt.find("labl").text],
            "Max": [txt.find(attrs={"type": "max"}).text],
            "Min": [txt.find(attrs={"type": "min"}).text],
        }
    )
    ref = ref.append(part)
```

With those problems resolved, we have a new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/souptest.py", line 23, in <module>
    "Min": [txt.find(attrs={"type": "min"}).text],
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The question becomes: how do we handle entries that are missing these
attributes? Since you were previously discarding the entire entry in
these situations, we can continue to that by re-introducing the
`try`/`except` block, now that we've solved the problem around the
question text:

```
for txt in soup:
    try:
        part = pd.DataFrame(
            data={
                "ID": [txt.attrs["name"]],
                "Qn": [txt.find("qstn").find("qstnLit").text],
                "Lbl": [txt.find("labl").text],
                "Max": [txt.find(attrs={"type": "max"}).text],
                "Min": [txt.find(attrs={"type": "min"}).text],
            }
        )
        ref = ref.append(part)
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Note that rather than using a blank `except`, I'm capturing the *specific* exception we expect to receive when there is a missing attribute.

This code now runs without errors. But does it work? If we print out
`ref` after the loop:

```
print(ref)
```

We seem to have found some results:

```
      ID                                                 Qn                                                Lbl                  Max                  Min
0   a3_1  \n          Please identify which of the follo...                      \n        Food safety\n        \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0   a3_2  \n          Please identify which of the follo...         \n        Non-communicable disease\n        \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0   a3_3  \n          Please identify which of the follo...  \n        Gender equity (closing the gap betwe...  \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0   a3_4  \n          Please identify which of the follo...       \n        Private sector development\n        \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0   a3_5  \n          Please identify which of the follo...                        \n        Education\n        \n        1\n        \n        0\n
..   ...                                                ...                                                ...                  ...                  ...
0   h6_2  \n          Which of the following describes m...  \n        Use World Bank Group reports/data\n ...  \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0   h6_3  \n          Which of the following describes m...  \n        Engage in World Bank Group related/s...  \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0   h6_4  \n          Which of the following describes m...  \n        Collaborate as part of my profession...  \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0   h6_5  \n          Which of the following describes m...  \n        Use World Bank Group website for inf...  \n        1\n        \n        0\n
0     h8             \n          What's your age?\n                         \n        What's your age?\n        \n        5\n        \n        2\n

[279 rows x 5 columns]
```

The tl;dr here is that your problems had nothing to do with the CDATA
blocks. Rather, your `try`/`except` block was hiding errors that would
help you resolve the problem. By at least temporarily removing that
block, we were able to detect and correct code errors.